# adding pre defined frameworks like (AddressBook.framework,CoreGraphics.framework)etc. into my custom framework(a static library)?

Tags: cocoa, xcode

i have made a framework with the help of this link:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/05/making-your-own-iphone-frameworks-in-xcode/

but it does not tells how to add pre defined frameworks into it(such as AddressBook,CoreGraphics etc.).

when i tried adding the frameworks(predefined) to it ,it shows the error:

```
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//AddressBook.framework/AddressBook) on link line
```

can anyone please suggest me how to add the predefined frameworks into the custom framework that i made...so that the end user is unknown of the dependent frameworks that i am using..????

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have add the predefined framework to your lib similar as we do in any project. But you also will have to add all those framework (added to your custom framework) to the project in which you are using your custom framework. So list all the included framework in the documentation of custom framework.

Comment: thanks....but is there no way that user need not add the dependent frameworks....i want the user to add only my framework and not the dependent one...?????

Comment: no, actually when we add any framework to the project it just take reference, don't copy it to project. So you have to add it again.

Comment: thanks jitendra for the answer......but is there any other way in which I can add a module (several classes) to my project which is as simple as adding a framework..for instance.......?????

Comment: When you add any external classes or library/custom framework, unfortunately you’ll have to add required framework for those added classes or library/custom framework.